# mongodb pull not working, my query dosn't work

Tags: mongodb

I have some problem with pull query
I have document bellow

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("59f68bfd5d7482787cb045ce"),
        "data_result" : [
                {
                        "13" : {
                                "id" : 13,
                                "preview_picture_url" : "",
                                "datetime" : "2017-03-21 13:46:52",
                                "detection_method_color_id" : 1,
                                "name" : "No Name"
                        }
                }
        ]
}
```

i want to remove "13" inside "data_result" from document, 
I tried this query

```
db.userdata.update( 
    {"_id" : ObjectId("59f68bfd5d7482787cb045ce")},  
    { $pull : 
        {"data_result" :
            { "13" : {} } 
        }
    }
)
```

it says nMatched 1 but doesnt pull the element, please help

Comment: You mean `$pull: { "data_result": { "13": { "$exists": true } } }`. The object is not "empty" so the condition you are using does not match. `$exists` will.

Comment: really thanks, it works